# Sending element to second sink if only first sink is successful

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I want to do following using akka streams..I tried broadcast ,and alsoTo but it didn't solve my problem

Source -> DBSink -> APISink.

I first want to  send element to DB, when transaction successfully completed,I want to send it to APISink..
if transaction fails in first Sink,I don't want to send it to API..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Akka Stream connect to multiple sinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119221/akka-stream-connect-to-multiple-sinks)

Comment: No,I dont want broadcast... I first want to send it to DB,when transaction is completed I want to send it to second sink.. broadcast basically doing alsoTo..

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve.

You can send elements from a Source to multiple sinks using [alsoTo](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/alsoTo.html).

> Attaches the given Sink to this Flow, meaning that elements that pass through this Flow will also be sent to the Sink.

```scala
val sink1 = Sink.foreach[Int](_ => "got it at sink1")
val sink2 = Sink.foreach[Int](_ => "got it at sink2")

Source(List(1, 2, 3))
  .alsoTo(sink1)
  .to(sink2)
```

The elements will be sent to both sinks only when both of them emit "demand". This behaves in the same way as `Broadcast`.

In case of an error, ie exception is being thrown in the stream processing, both sinks will be notified with an error and stream stops by default. 
It's matter of supervision strategy to say if stream needs stopping, restarting or resuming.

```
.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.resumingDecider))
```

Comment: Here is exactly what i want .. First I want to send it to db, after db transaction is committed ,I want to send it to second sink.. alsoTo wont do it..

Comment: If you're aiming to keep your stream alive then you have to handle exceptions yourself. 
 If you're using an asynchronous db client that return a `Future[Try[Result]]` (replace Result with whatever your result type is supposed to be) then return that in a `mapAsync`, and then match on the `Try` downstream in another `mapAsync`/`map`.  Call your API when it's a success.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use a `Flow` for the database operation. The database flow should return some sort of composite object (e.g. a `Pair`, or a `Try`) that contain the data needed for the next step *and* the result of the database operation.

If the “unsuccessful” database operation means it throws an exception, you will definitely have to use a Try. Because if the database flow throws an exception, the stream will stop.  If the database operation being “unsuccessful” is a negative result (e.g. not enough credit for operation, product code doesn’t exist in the db, something like that), then you can use a Pair which contains both the database result (maybe just a Boolean) *and* the data payload. If it’s *both* you will have to use a Try which contains a Pair so you can intercept both the exception cases and the “computer says no” business logic cases.

However the *key* here, is this is done with a `Flow`, not a `Sink`. A Sink consumes the data. A flow will both consume and return data, which is what you want.

On the result of the database Flow, you put a `filter()` or a `filterNot()` on the stream to remove the unsuccessful results, and after that pass it onto to downstream Sink (or another Flow) that completes the API call.